# spark-submit from a kubernetes pod to a MAPR cluster running spark in yarn

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have been working on deploying airflow 2.0 in k8s. As part of that I am tasked with getting the sparksubmitoperator working. I was able to take the airflow image and add in all the mapr spark packages and get the operator to submit work. Now my problem is that the submit sends the name of the pods dns name which only exists inside the k8s cluster. The MAPR cluster running spark on yarn is external to the cluster. I see this error in the app logs.

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: airflow-worker-1.airflow-worker.airflow.svc.cluster.local

It makes sense, the app is trying to communicate back to the client. I thought I would just set hostnetwork to true on the statefulset for the airflow workers, but that broke communication of the workers with the rest of airflow. The pods errored and went into a restart loop.

Is there is a way to set the name of the client in the spark-submit? I could set an ENV variable to .spec.nodename and pass that as the host. I think that might work. But I am not certain. Another idea I have is to change the service for the workers to type LB. I don't know that it is going to resolve the issue either since I don't think the LB address will get registered in DNS. It's an interesting issue to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I got around my issue by using cluster mode with the sparksubmitoperator in airflow.